# Laravel 5.2 Auth::User Foreign Key Join Query

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, laravel-5

I'm new to Laravel.

I add a new column named `permission` in default `User` table. And it's a foreign key related to `p_id` in `Permissions` table `(user.permission = permissions.p_id)`。

One user belongs to a Permission grade (`p_id`), but a Permission  grade can be belonged to many users.

```
[DB FIELDS]

user
- ...
- permission

permission 
- p_id
- p_permission
- p_title
```

And my Eloquent Model definition

```
[App\Permission]

public function user() {
    return $this->hasMany('App\Permission', 'p_id');
}
```

```
[App\User]

public function permission() {
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Permission', 'permission', 'p_id');
}
```

In Controller, how do I query `p_title` or other `permission.*` fields?

I've tried

```
echo Auth::User()->permission->p_title;
echo User::find(1)->permission->p_title;
```

both are return `Trying to get property of non-object`,

And

```
echo Auth::User()->with('permission')->get();
```

returns all the users. (What I want is the logged in user)

How can I query `Auth::User()` with foreign key just like use `Auth::User()->p_title` as easy?

Thank you so much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your Permission model relation is incorrect.

[App\Permission]

```
public function users() {
    return $this->hasMany('App\User', 'permission');
}
```

Comment: I changed my code this way, but not work. 
`Auth::User()->permission->p_title`  still returns 

`Trying to get property of non-object `

Comment: Why don't you use `tinker` and try to debug? Try `$u = App\User::first()`, then `$u->permission`. See whether you get anything.

Answer (score 0):

Can You Check this in your permission model

```
App/Permission

protected $table = 'Permission';
protected $primaryKey = 'p_id';
```